# pyramid_jinja2: ImportError: cannot import name Environment

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid

I'm going through the tutorial for the Pyramid framework and I'm currently stuck at the one that [teaches the use of Jinja2 as the templating engine.](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/jinja2.html). It seems that when I run the test using `nosetests`, I get this odd ImportError stating that the name Environment couldn't be imported from the Jinja2 module. Funny thing is, when I `pserve` the site, it works just fine. It seems like this error will only occur during the test...I am currently working off a virtualenv using Ubuntu 14.04.

Any suggestions?

Here's the stack trace...

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_home (jinja2.tutorial.tests.TutorialFunctionalTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/quick_tutorial/jinja2/tutorial/tests.py", line 30, in setUp
    app = main({})
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/quick_tutorial/jinja2/tutorial/__init__.py", line 5, in main
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 727, in include
    c = self.maybe_dotted(callable)
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 825, in maybe_dotted
    return self.name_resolver.maybe_resolve(dotted)
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 320, in maybe_resolve
    return self._resolve(dotted, package)
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 327, in _resolve
    return self._zope_dottedname_style(dotted, package)
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 376, in _zope_dottedname_style
    found = __import__(used)
  File "/home/bk/pg/pyramid/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_jinja2-2.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment as _Jinja2Environment
ImportError: cannot import name Environment

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Michael Merickel is right. You have a conflict between your `jinja2` module and real one. This mistake grows from python2 import politics. But you can add to first line of your script magic sentence `from __future__ import absolute_import`. It changes relative import to absolute.

More information: [PEP 0328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports)

But my solution doesn't help you if you want to execute your script from `/home/bk/pg/pyramid/quick_tutorial/`. Because in this situation where will be two possible way to resolve `import jinja2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say but my first guess is that it looks like you named your project `jinja2` and that's going to conflict with the `jinja2` package in some weird ways depending on what module is doing the imports etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case where I was using  `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all packages for a Django project on an Ubuntu machine, I ran into this error and many other installation errors.

To solve this one, I uninstalled and reinstalled Jinja2, and it worked.

Also, be careful to use pip3/pip3.x based on which Python version you are using instead of just pip because the default python interpreter in Ubuntu is Python2.7