# I want to use simiki to create my own wiki,but some errors happened when i "simiki init "in the terminal

Tags: python

➜  mywiki python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > exit()
> > >       ➜  mywiki simiki new -t "Hello Simiki" -c first-catetory
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/usr/local/bin/simiki", line 9, in 
> > >           load_entry_point('simiki==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'simiki')()
> > >         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
> > >           return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
> > >         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
> > >           return ep.load()
> > >         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
> > >           entry = **import**(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['**name**'])
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simiki/cli.py", line 53, in 
> > >           from simiki.generators import (PageGenerator, CatalogGenerator, FeedGenerator)
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simiki/generators.py", line 23, in 
> > >           from jinja2 import (Environment, FileSystemLoader, TemplateError)
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/**init**.py", line 33, in 
> > >           from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 14, in 
> > >           from jinja2.defaults import BLOCK_START_STRING, \
> > >         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 32, in 
> > >           from jinja2.tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name TESTS

Comment: Which part of `ImportError: cannot import name TESTS` do you need help with?  Be aware that Python module names should have the same case as the file name.

Answer (score 0):

See the following Stack Overflow post:

You have a conflict between your jinja2 module and the real one. This mistake grows from Python 2 import politics. But you can add this to the first line of your script:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

*[pyramid_jinja2: ImportError: cannot import name Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271419/pyramid-jinja2-importerror-cannot-import-name-environment/31279085#31279085)*